# Is there any function for reprent final day of year in mysql

Tags: mysql

i want to add all sum of values of `reg_data3` table of column `rainfall` to `average_mas_curve` table column year of last year and all of values in past data of previous years as a summation  but i want to represent as a function of last day of year please give me it.......help me.
e.g `y-12-31`.

```
INSERT INTO mas_aver_curve (year, cumulative) 
    SELECT '2013-12-31', ROUND(SUM(rainfall), 1) rainfall 
    FROM reg_data3 G 
    WHERE date >= '2008-01-01' AND date <  '2013-12-31'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
INSERT INTO mas_aver_curve (year, cumulative) 
    SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(year(NOW())-1,'-12-31'),'%Y-%m-%d') AS LastDay, 
           ROUND(SUM(rainfall), 1) rainfall 
    FROM reg_data3 G 
    WHERE date >= '2008-01-01' AND date <  '2013-12-31'
    GROUP BY 1;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo for the str_to_date part](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/26160)</kbd>

Comment: i add to this automatically run when final day of the year. add to regular day-wise data via form in php i change like this it is correct

Comment: @SasinduRHN. I'm sorry but i didn't understand what you meant in your last comment.

Comment: from this give5 raws give sum of rainfall in all year in year wise but i wantt in sum of years values....... 2008+2009+2010+2011+2012 rainfalls give end of 2012 this code doesnt give it

Comment: You want only the SUM for every year in the same row, having 2012-12-31 as the left column?

Comment: yes Mr. Silva i want sum of left column i am new comer plase help me

Comment: I edited my query. This should give you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can select the year and sum using

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(date), 
    ROUND(SUM(rainfall), 1) 
FROM reg_data3
WHERE YEAR(date)>=2008 AND YEAR(date)<=2013
GROUP BY YEAR(date)
```

and then put that in the insert.

Comment: i add to this automaticall run when final day of the year. add to regular daywise data via form in mysql but this code i can't do it